# nice of or from you ? which one is correct?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

Do we say

> That's nice of you.

or

> That's nice from you.

?
If both, what's the difference in meaning ?

Comment: "Nice from you" is very strange and non-fluent-sounding.  Did you find this sentence used somewhere?

Comment: @stangdon I didn't. I just derived it from the Czech "od Tebe".

Answer (score 2):

**That's nice of you**
is the idiomatic way of saying it.

"That's nice from you" is non-standard and might be taken as sarcastic as there is a similar idiomatic phrasing "that's [adjective] *coming* from you" that is often used sarcastically

Comment: Agreed. If someone said, "That's nice from you," it would be expressing at the best, surprise at unusual treatment; sarcasm would be the usual usage. Also, this usage omits *coming* which is even more common.